# Push to array from constructor in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor, push

I'm trying to build an array of objects from within the constructor. I don't know if it's even possible or advisable. But I'm trying to build this for practice, and I wonder why it isn't working.

```js
// Variables.
const VVD = new Party("VVD", 33);

// List of objects.
var theList = [];

// Party constructor.
function Party(name, seats) {
 this.name = name;
 this.seats = seats;
 //theList.push(this); // This isn't working.
 this.pushToTheList = function() { 
  theList.push(this);
 }
 this.pushToTheList(); // And neither is this.
}
```

This is the error I'm getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` Even if I replace `this` with `"test"`, I'm still getting the same error.

While outside of the constructor, this is working fine:
`theList.push(VVD);`

Why isn't this working? And is there a better, smarter way to push objects to arrays?

A link to CodePen: http://codepen.io/MichaelVanDenBerg/pen/gmXZej

Comment: `function Party` happens to be *hoisted*; `theList = []` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Party` constructor is being called *before* you create your `theList` array.

Function declarations (like your `Party` constructor) are hoisted to the top of their scope; however, assignments to variables like `theList = []` are not (even though the `var theList` declaration itself is hoisted). Thus, your code is being interpreted like this:

```
var theList;

// Variables.
const VVD = new Party("VVD", 33);

// List of objects.
theList = [];
```

You can see more clearly here why `theList` is `undefined` when your constructor is first called. Try reordering the statements so that `theList` is created before `VVD`:

```js
// List of objects.
var theList = [];

// Variables.
const VVD = new Party("VVD", 33);


// Party constructor.
function Party(name, seats) {
 this.name = name;
 this.seats = seats;
 //theList.push(this); // This works
 this.pushToTheList = function() { 
  theList.push(this);
 }
 this.pushToTheList(); // And so does this.
}

console.log(theList)
```

Comment: Well… `var` actually *is* hoisted; the `= []` assignment is not… </nitpick>

Comment: you shouldn't create `Party` before you define `Party`

Comment: @stackoverfloweth That doesn't matter, due to function declaration hoisting. It's a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'm still doing something wrong, but even if I reorder the code, it still isn't working. As you can see in my CodePen: http://codepen.io/MichaelVanDenBerg/pen/gmXZej

Comment: You added a third argument to your constructor (`theList`) which should not be there. If you remove it, the code works fine.

Comment: Why not, after `this.seats = seats;` , have only : `theList.push(this);` ?

Answer (score 0):

you created a new `Party` before you defined `theList`

```
// List of objects.
var theList = [];

// Party constructor.
function Party(name, seats) {
    this.name = name;
    this.seats = seats;
    //theList.push(this); // This isn't working.
    this.pushToTheList = function() { 
        theList.push(this);
    }
    this.pushToTheList(); // And neither is this.
}

// Variables.
const VVD = new Party("VVD", 33);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Variables.
const VVD = new Party("VVD", 33);

// List of objects.
var theList = [];

// Party constructor.
function Party(name, seats) {
    this.name = name;
    this.seats = seats;
    //theList.push(this); // This isn't working.
    this.pushToTheList = function() { 
        theList.push(this);
    }
    this.pushToTheList(); // And neither is this.
}
```